# RDP into a Windows 10 virtual machine without router connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, remote-desktop

Referring to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/985076/vpn-rdp-without-a-router), it doesn't solve my problem.

I am using Windows 10 Pro. Inside that Windows-10 Pro VM

Network Map:

[image]

- *Windows 10 - PC1 Connected Directly using Dialup Connection ISP-1*
- *VM -Windows 10- PC1-2 NAT Connection*
- *Macbook Connected ISP-2 using Wi-FI*

I am trying to connect Windows inside VM. Using the public IP of the host machine(PC1). But not able to make connection.

- RDP Enabled PC1
- RDP Enabled PC1-2

What I am doing wrong?

IP Config: https://www.paste.org/101484

Comment: Are you sure you even have your own public IP address on ISP 2? Because the `ipconfig` output doesn’t show one.

Comment: @DanielB I think no I can only see DNS Server. which is public only.

Comment: @DanielB I connecting using public IP which is my current Public IP

Comment: If you don’t have a public IP address on the dial-up connection this cannot work, sorry. Your ISP 2 is most likely using [carrier-grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT).

Comment: @twister_void Out of curiosity, why are you using the broadcast subnet mask (`255.255.255.255`) as the subnet mask of the `10.10.202.x` subnet?

Comment: @JW0914 A subnet mask of 255.255.255.255 does not mean broadcast. In fact, it prevents any and all broadcast. That’s to be expected: It’s a point-to-point connection.

Comment: @DanielB How I can check for public IP on a dial-up connection or is there any  way to work around this

Comment: You check it the way you’re doing now. You don’t have a public IP address. There is no way around this without third-party services (eg. tunnel services). I don’t know any of these though, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The solution depends upon what hypervisor you're utilizing:

### Hyper-V

- **Win10 Host:**

  1. **Hyper-V Manager** > Virtual Switch Manager - New virtual network switch
  2. **Type:** Internal > Create Virtual Switch > OK
  3. **Windows Explorer:** `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections`

     1. Right-click on new internal vSwitch > Properties
     2. Double-click *Internet Protocol Version 4* > Use the following IP address:
     3. Assign an RFC1918 IP that's not apart of an RFC1918 LAN subnet you're connected to

        - **IP address:** `192.168.255.1`
        - **Subnet Mask:** `255.255.255.252` || `255.255.255.248`
     4. OK > OK
- **Win10 VM:**

  1. **Hyper-V Manager** > VM Settings > Hardware > Add Hardware - Network Adapter > Add

     - Hardware > Network Adapter - Virtual Switch: Select the *New Internal Switch* > OK
  2. **Boot VM:**

     1. Repeat step **3** from *Win10 Host*:

        - **IP address:** `192.168.255.2`
        - **Subnet Mask:** Same as selected for the *Win10 Host*
     2. OK > OK

Connect via RDP to the Win10 VM on IP address `192.168.255.2`

---

### Other Hypervisor

Windows can't natively create vLANs due to its network stack lacking this functionality.

- To get around this, use the OpenVPN TAP adapter:

  1. **Install:** [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/)
  2. **<kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>** > **Open:** `cmd` > Hold **<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>** > OK - *approve escalation*
  3. **Issue:**

     ```powershell
     "C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\bin\tapinstall.exe" install "C:\Program Files\TAP-Windows\driver\OemVista.inf" tap0901
     ```
  4. **Follow steps from above:**

     - Win10 Host: *#3*
     - Win10 VM: *#2*
  5. **vSwitch Adapater Settings** > Configure

     - Advanced tab - Media Status - Always Connected > OK

Connect via RDP to the Win10 VM on IP address `192.168.255.2`